# MOSS Search Index clean up

Tags: 2007, search

I have a SharePoint 2007 farm that has an index server and two query servers. The query servers are also the WFE's. I am running out of space on my index server. I have cleaned up all that I can from the drive the index files are located on. Now I am looking at the index files and I am curious if I can delete files older than the last full crawl. The last full crawl completed on 9/8 and I see a lot of files that are older than this. Can I delete all of the files older than 9/8 without affecting search? Currently my index directory is at 58GB where the query servers only have 18GB for the index. So I am thinking I have 40GB of junk. Thanks

Comment: that will teach me to remember to go back to my questions and mark answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

40gb, it's your crawl index database log I'm sure unless you have a stupidly large sharepoint installation.

This has been answered before so here is [how to reduce all the empty space.](http://www.aiim.org/community/blogs/expert/Is-your-search-database-bloated)

If you happen to have a massive installation I would look at some more storage space and look into spreading your index over a couple of dedicated drives. (But I doubt it is this)

Comment: It wasnt the search database but the index files that were taking up all the space. It finally ended up cleaning itself up once it got to a certain point, not sure how it decided where that point was. Now I have 38GB back. Thanks for the link.